# Как понять почему kubernetes pod бы пересоздан

Tags: kubernetes

Что есть:

- 2 кластера по 6 подов в каждом
- развертывание через helm (тоесть поды подымаються одинаковые на 2 кластерах)
- в подах используються health checkers c 3 попытками рестарта
- логи сохраняються во внешнем хранилище

Проблема:

- только на втором кластере епизодически некоторые поды переподымаються
- поды перегружаються без попыток рестарта, тоесть нету истории предедущего падения
- в логах нету информаци об ошибках приложения

Что нужно:

- понять причину переподнятия подов

Что делал:

- гуглил где кубернетис хранит информацию почему он решил перегрузить под. Единственное нашел

  - kubectl describe pod (где можно увидить статус падения предедущего перезапуска) но это непомогает так как под не пытался рестартовать а
    сразу был убит и занаво поднят
  - kubectl events (следить за
    событиями в кластере) но еще не выловил нужное событие так как поды
    могут падать 5 раз на день а потом пару дней работать хорошо
- гугли когда кубернетис может убивать поды. Нашел:

  - только если хелсчекер падает (это не мой случай)
  - достигнуты лимиты по ресурсам (пока что думаю что это мой случай), но немогу найти команды которые подтвердили бы мне что под выходил за рамки лимитов

Comment: А у вас sentry используются? Наши админы к кластеру прикрутили sentry, и там видно когда что рестартилось. Чаще всего сообщения такие прилетают Readiness probe failed, 90% возникает по oom killer. Ну и describe это то же отражает

Comment: у меня есть опыт с oom killer как раз по причине Readiness probe, и я его именно через describe видел в секции причины рестарта. Но тут ситуация хуже, так как убитый под не оставляет следов, а новый под был создан планировщиком поэтому describe ничего не знает. За sentry спасибо, щас посмотрю что это